# Is it possible a block a contact in lumia 520?

Tags: lumia, lumia-520, call-sms-filter

I need to block a certain phone number from contacting me. I don't know where to find this option in Nokia Lumia 520. Can someone please help with this issue?

Comment: What Os Version do you use?

Comment: i use windows 8.0 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i figured out a way to block contacts in Nokia Lumia 520. For that we need to update the accesories and the Extra+info from the store. Then you will have the call+sms filter in Lumia black of Lumia 520. Additionally you also get a option called touch. If you double tap the screen, it will wake up. We can use this instead of power button.

Comment: After updated the accesories and the Extra+info from the store. Then i will not seen any call+sms filter option in Lumia 520 anyone can help me?

Answer (score 11):

In the history list, tap and hold on the offending number, and choose "block number...".

To check on the list of currently blocked numbers, go to **settings** -> **call+SMS filter**, and tap on blocked numbers. You can also use the advanced button to block witheld numbers, pin to the start screen, and control whether you get notifications when there is blocked activity.

Whilst the "blocked" SMS messages don't show in the SMS app, they do show within the filter, so you can still get Google secondary authentication tokens, etc.

Comment: @VivekParekh Thanks Vivek - I use this feature *a lot*, and find it handy for blocking cold calls, and also found out "the hard way" about Google's sign-in confirmation emails - my recommendation would be to pin the app as a small tile...

Comment: @rowland shaw: i use lumia 520 with windows 8. When i tap and hold the number in the history, it gives me a single option to delete item. Also i dint find anything in the name as call+sms filter in the settings. Please help me with some others options or do i need to upgrade to windows 8.1 to avail this option

Comment: You shouldn't need 8.1 for this feature, but be aware that some standard options *can* be blocked by your network provider; It's possible that the feature is blocked for you. In either respect, to check you have the latest published version, simply swipe across to **settings** -> **phone update**, and check for updates there; You should also check for updates in the store - it will indicate the number of updates on its live tile, or have an entry at the bottom of the screen when you go into the store app.

Comment: Are you talking about any application that can block calls or is it an inbuild functionality in lumia 520?

Comment: This is functionality that is part of Windows Phone for all Lumia phones running 8.0 or later.

Comment: Okay. If so where can i find that option. Can you put some screenshots.

Answer (score 3):

### Call + SMS filter (for Nokia Lumia phones only)

- Swipe right to the app list
- Scroll down until you find 'Settings' (tap)
- System
- Scroll down until you find 'call+SMS filter' down the list, then tap to open

Answer (score 0):

Turn on Block calls+SMS in the call+SMS filter app.

Go to Phone on the Start Screen.
In call history, long-tap the phone number or contact you want to block.
Select block number.. from the drop-down menu.
The phone will ask you to confirm.
If you agree, the phone number will be added to the blocked list.
or

Go to Messaging.
On the threads, long-tap the phone number or contact you want to block.
Select block number.. from the drop down menu.
The phone will ask you to confirm.
If you agree, the phone number will be added to the blocked list.
After the phone number is added to the blocked number list, you will no longer receive any calls or text messages from that number.

Note: You cannot block MMS or IM messages with the call+SMS filter app.

Answer (score 0):

To blacklist contacts in Lumia 520.Simply update the call and SMS filter.Then go to the call history pick the number by a long hold then a delete and  block option appears.Then do the necessary.

Comment: I have not any "sms+call" setting on my Lumia520 mobile setting. Please, suggest me how I reject and block a call.

Comment: And I have no "call+sms filter app". How I block a call? And when I select this number and long tap this phone number the I see only details, delete and add to speed dail options, there is no "block number" option. Please, early reply..